# Javascript - CORS no response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, cross-domain

I have website: http://www.bluegreenblack.com/p/weather-in-ireland.html

Wanted to add Metar readings from: https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=EIDW

I want to use Javascript with CORS.

Here is the code(copypasta from other [website](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)):

```
<script language="Javascript">

// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=csv&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=EIDW';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert(text);
    //alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    //alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    alert(xhr.statusText);
  };

  xhr.send();
}

makeCorsRequest()

</script>
```

I am getting response:

```
**General**
    Request URL:https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=csv&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=EIDW
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK
    Remote Address:140.90.101.207:443

**Response Headers**

Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/x-csv
Date:Wed, 13 Apr 2016 21:28:12 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=300, max=98
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Via:1.1 aviationweather.ncep.noaa.gov
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

**Request Headers**

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:www.aviationweather.gov
Origin:http://www.bluegreenblack.com
Referer:http://www.bluegreenblack.com/p/weather-in-ireland.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36

**Query String Parameters**

view URL encoded
dataSource:metars
requestType:retrieve
format:csv
hoursBeforeNow:3
mostRecent:true
stationString:EIDW
```

But no response...

I have this error in log:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSourc…pe=retrieve&format=csv&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=EIDW. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.bluegreenblack.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I get valid data using python urllib2 it this is of any use...

Comment: It looks as if server may not support that:  An XMLHttpRequest was made to a domain that was different than your page's domain. This requires the server to return an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in its response headers, but one was not returned.  The server must support CORS requests and return an appropriate "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header with the resource. See CORS for XHR in IE10 for more info about CORS in response headers.   If this is the case. What are my options?

Comment: one option can be to create a page in your web server which will do the request to **aviationweather** then return the results as text or json or something, and call this page via javascript instead

Answer (score 0):

most likely that server does not support CORS requests. Have you tried to call this service from your web server and create your own web service to serve for your page?

Comment: I have very limited access. My web is a wrapper of blogger.

Comment: so you stuck with java script :( why don't you find another domain for weather report @vic152

Comment: I found this on the web: https://www.aviationweather.gov/help/webservice?page=metarjson I am not a big web programmer so it's double dutch to me...

Comment: @vic152 just find another domain.