# How to avoid error parsing xml with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml from NOAA website with this code:

```
fetch("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=EDDK&hoursBeforeNow=4",
{mode: 'no-cors'})
         .then(response => response.text())
         .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
         .then(data => console.log(data));
```

But I obtain this error:

```
This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Any suggestions to use the xml?
Otherwise, can I avoid the problem using the result as text and then some regex search? I need only the first `data->METAR->raw_text` in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the same issue here: [Javascript - CORS no response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610276/javascript-cors-no-response)

If you test, you can see `response.text()` is empty. Not sure if the API is intended to be public or not, but it seems like if you want to fetch it, you'll have to do it from some backend server and not a browser.

Comment: I found https://api.met.no/weatherapi/tafmetar/1.0/documentation#!/data/get_info that is working. Thanks